# Export to .csv from APEX (Oracle Application Express) is suppressing some column values

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-apex

I have created an Interactive Report using Oracle Application Express (APEX). The problem is that when downloading to `.csv` there is a colum (string format with a number value) that is getting changed in the `.csv` export.  For example, the column value reads `123456789` on the screen in the Interactive Report.  However, once the report is downloaded to `.csv`, the value is `123456780`.  It is changing the last  value to a "0" but only on the export.  I have searched the Net to no avail. This occurs automatically (the `.csv` column has not been formatted at all only exported from APEX).  Anyone know why this is occurring? Is it an APEX bug??

Comment: Can you provide the source table definition? Specifically the definition of that column. Is it really a VARCHAR, or similar, or is it of a numeric type? And is this altered value present when you view the CSV file as a text file, or are you viewing it in a spreadsheet (Excel)?

Comment: After taking a look at the .csv file through a text reader (Context) I was able to see that the value is correct EXCEPT when Microsoft Excel is used to open the file.  Therefore, I now know that the issue is not with Oracle APEX but instead with Microsoft Excel.  I need to figure out why Excel isn't treating all the values as text (instead of converting values to various data types).

Comment: Does this value really contains 10 digits? As I remember, that Excel can work with numbers of 14 or 15 digits, if number length is higher, Excel rounds it (and you see zeros). You can add symbol `'` before the number, and Excel will treat it as a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

if your decimal separator is comma, instead of "."

Maybe Excel is considering your commas which have been used to seperate values, as a decimal place separator and round your value up :)

for instance a content like 123456789,99 maybe rounding to 123456790